# Why Xcode automatically changes `xcschememanagement.plist` file while checking out a branch?

Tags: ios, xcode, git

While checking out different branches you see that a file named `xcschememanagement.plist` is changed (Xcode was open at the time)

Why even if you discard all local changes and checkout another branch Xcode still changes the file?